# Dissimilar-root radical equation

Tags: roots, radicals

Sorry I wasn't able to type the equation!
Here is the link and my problem is "task 15"
I'll highly appreciate if you answer this question
Thank you

> What is the solution to the infinite equation
>
> > $\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt[4]{x}\cdot\sqrt[8]{x}\cdot\sqrt[16]{x}\cdot\sqrt[32]{x}\cdot\ldots=16$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the logarithms of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 
$$ x^{1/2} \cdot x^{1/4} \cdot x^{1/8} \cdots = x^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots} = x^1 \text{.}  $$